Saved video has different aspect ratio than preview widget
Why does my recorded video get cropped on the sides, even though my CameraPreview shows the full frame?
I'm working on an Android app in Flutter, using the camera package (0.11.0+2). I set up my CameraPreview with a 0.75 (3:4) aspect ratio, and it shows the full frame just fine. However, when I record a video, the saved file is cropped on the sides. I’m not sure what’s causing this difference between the preview and the final recording.
I'm using the stream from the controller to do some pose detection, which works great. But if I record at the same time the video is cropped or of different aspect ration in the saved file.
Here’s the relevant code to show what I'm doing.  I's a very big file, so I thought I'd show just the parts I think is needed, but let me know if you want me to show more of my code:
// Camera preview with aspect ratio setting
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: AspectRatio(
    aspectRatio: _aspectRatio, // 0.75 for 3:4 preview aspect ratio
    child: CameraPreview(
      _cameraController!,
      child: _customPaint,
    ),
  ),
),

// Initialize camera controller
final CameraController cameraController = CameraController(
  cameraDescription,
  ResolutionPreset.low,  // Tried different resolutions here
  imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.nv21,
  enableAudio: false,
  fps: 25,
);


// Recording functions
Future<void> _startVideoRecording() async {
  if (_cameraController == null || _cameraController!.value.isRecordingVideo) return;

  try {
    await _cameraController!.startVideoRecording();
    setState(() => _isRecording = true);
  } on CameraException catch (e) {
    print('Error starting video recording: $e');
  }
}

Future<XFile?> _stopVideoRecording() async {
  if (_cameraController == null || !(_cameraController!.value.isRecordingVideo)) return null;

  try {
    XFile? videoFile = await _cameraController!.stopVideoRecording();
    setState(() => _isRecording = false);
    return videoFile;
  } on CameraException catch (e) {
    print('Error stopping video recording: $e');
    return null;
  }
}

